# Mysql tree traverse and count

Tags: php, mysql

I`ve got the following table in mysql

```
id|top_id|amount
 1    NULL     2
 2    NULL     8
 3    NULL     4
 4       3     7
 5       2     8
 6       2     4
 7       5     5
 8       7     1
 9       6     6
10       8     6
```

For the first 3 ids i need to sum up all amounts of its successors to get the following:

```
id   |  amount
1         8
2         32
3         11
```

I guess there should be joins but unfortunately I can`t get the working mysql request. Can somebody help me?

UPD: In php I have the following query:

```
$tops = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE top_id IS NULL')
```

which obviously returns me just 3 top ids and their plain amounts (2, 8 and 4 respectively). Instead of 2, 8 and 4 I need to get 12, 28 and 11 and that`s the problem((

Comment: Unless you have a set limit on how "deep" your tree can go, you can NOT do this with plain mysql. mysql doesn't support recursive queries. You can fake it for a certain depth by using self-joins, but arbitrary depth is basically impossible without using external loops in client-side code.

Comment: So, options include: joining the table to itself as often as could possibly be required; constructing a sproc to handle the recursion; using some external code to handle the recursion; amending the data model (to a nested set, say)

Comment: I need this for php code. May be there are some ideas to use a recursive query there?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: If you want to store and query a tree in mysql you should look into [closure tables](https://coderwall.com/p/lixing/closure-tables-for-browsing-trees-in-sql).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I am trying to build a query in php, but its depth is not recursive as I don`t know the depth of the tree and how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the crudest solution... No doubt someone will provide some hints for a more scalable solution shortly (perhaps employing PHP)...

```
SELECT a.id
     , COALESCE(a.amount,0)
     + COALESCE(b.amount,0)
     + COALESCE(c.amount,0)
     + COALESCE(d.amount,0)
     + COALESCE(e.amount,0)
     + COALESCE(f.amount,0) total 
  FROM my_table a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.top_id = a.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table c 
    ON c.top_id = b.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table d 
    ON d.top_id = c.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table e 
    ON e.top_id = d.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table f 
    ON f.top_id = e.id 
 WHERE a.top_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I`ll check this out

Comment: I found out that this solution does not work if we have several descendants of the one parent. I modified the first table. It counts separately for the user with ID 2 and does not add up everything((